# C: Scanf Ignored in Type Mismatch

Tags: c, loops, scanf, do-while

Yes, there are already similar issues on SO on that `scanf()` does not wait for the user's input before "interpreting" an enter keypress, but my problem is that this problem only occurs when the scan -- which is  `%ld` (with a space in front) -- reads a string instead of another long number. Details are below if this summary seems convoluted.

I have the following program in C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{
    long int cardnum, tmp;
    int num_of_digits;
    bool validate; // valid value
    LOOP:do
    {
        printf("Number: ");
        scanf(" %ld", &cardnum);

        tmp = cardnum, num_of_digits = 0;
        while (tmp != 0)
        {
            tmp /= 10;
            ++num_of_digits;
        }

        if (num_of_digits != 16)
        {
            printf("INVALID\n");
            goto LOOP;
        }

        validate = false;
        // ... (validate will be processed here, and there will be a case where "validate" will be true)
    }
    while (validate != true);
}
```

Inputs:

- `4003600000000014`: works, length is 16
- `400360000000001`: prints `INVALID`, length is 15
- `asdf`: infinite loop (**notice how not all invalid inputs will result in this bug!**)

```
Number: INVALID
Number: INVALID
Number: INVALID
...
```

I have read elsewhere that `scanf` ignores the last line buffer (or something) but in my case, it only happens when `scanf` did not receive the right input type from the user. Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what do you _want_ to happen on `asdf`? `goto LOOP;` that is horrible and do not use goto. Just `continue`.

Comment: That space before the format specifier never worked for me, so it's getting stuck on the newline in stdin, easier thing to do is use `getchar()` to get it out of there, better thing to do is read it with `fgets` and convert it to an `int`

Comment: @KamilCuk if `asdf` was entered I'd like to have the user input again. The purpose of the `goto` was to not enter the processes below for optimization purposes. If there's a function that does the same but is "better," please let me know

Comment: What should I use instead then? But the error described in the problem persists even if I used `continue`.

Comment: @LEF, a literal space character in the format string matches however much whitespace appears at the corresponding point in the input, including none.  However, *most* conversion specifiers, including `%d`, ignore any leading whitespace anyway, so format `" %ld"` matches exactly the same inputs that `"%ld"` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how not all invalid inputs will result in this bug!)

If your input is not a number, then `scanf` will fail. So check if it fails to scan a number and if the scanning failed, then ignore the input until the end of line, for example. Note - you should handle `EOF` too.

```
if (scanf(...) != 1) {
    int c;
    // ignore input
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        // until a newline!
        if (c == '\n') {
            break;
        }
    }
    // when eof
    if (c == EOF) {
        // then exit our program with a failure!
        printf("ERROR: End of input!");
        exit(-1);
    }
    // if not eof, means user is ready to enter yet another line
    printf("you inputted an invalid line - please input a line consisting of digits only!");
    continue;
}
```

See return value description in [cppreference scanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

---

`LOOP:do {` and `goto LOOP;` looks like a horrible idea - do not use goto there, seems confusing. Instead prefer to restructure your code so that you do not have to use goto. For example:

```
for (;;) {
    if (some_check) {
         continue;
    }
    if (some_another_check) {
         continue;
    }
    // if we get here, means all checks succeeded - so we need to break
    break;
}
```

There are nice uses of goto and it happens to be used - see ex. https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html#centralized-exiting-of-functions .

Comment: Can I know what did you replace `scanf(" %ld", &cardnum);` with? It's a bit difficult for me to understand what you're trying to do here (especially `if (scanf(...) != 1) {`)

Comment: `if (scanf(" %ld", &cardnum) != 1) {` - I use `..` as a placeholder.

Comment: What does `!= 1` mean?

Comment: Here you may find some C books that may introduce you to the C programming language: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list .

Answer (score 1):

If you entered something other than an integer number then you need to remove from the input buffer the invalid input.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    long int x;
    int valid;
    
    do
    {
        if ( !( valid = ( scanf( " %ld", &x ) == 1 ) ) && valid != EOF )
        {
            scanf( "%*[^\n]%*c");
        }
    } while ( !valid );
    
    printf( "x = %ld\n", x );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The console output might look like

```
A
12
x = 12
```

Pay attention to that using the `goto` statement is a bad programming style. Instead you could use do-while statement as it is shown in my program. That is in fact the `goto` statement in your program is redundant.